# How can I rotate an object around its local Y axis rather than the global Y axis using actionscript-3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I have a flat object, eventually it will be a circle, but for now I just have a 2d square on the stage. I tip it back 75 degrees, and then rotate it around the y axis.

I have this code which has the object rotating, but it rotates around the global Y axis. But I want it to rotate around it's own Y axis which is tipped 15 degrees from vertical.

```
box_mc.rotationY=0;
box_mc.rotationX=-75;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onYRotate);

function onYRotate(e:Event):void{
    box_mc.rotationY+=2;
}
```

Can someone help me change my code so it rotates on its own Y axis?

Comment: Wrap it, in short. Use a container that you'd rotate by X to -75, then rotate the object inside around the container's Y axis which will be in your required position.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, although it is taking a while to get it in the right place with the right perspective. Thanks for your help.